# Can I make my own Heroku with Micro Cloud Foundry and a Rackspace cloud server?

Tags: web-applications, heroku, application-server, rackspace

I'm looking to deploy applications to my own cloud server as simply as it can be done to Heroku, is Micro Cloud Foundry a viable way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's depends of your needs.

**Method 1**

If you need your own instance of CloudFoundry you can [download the micro instance](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/micro_cloud_foundry/) and use it as your private PaaS.  It's a simple Ubuntu VM with services on it.

Pros:

- You can deploy it on any public or private cloud you want.
- Cheap to run and use.

Cons:

- Not all features will be available
- You will max out your VM quickly

**Method 2**

You can purchase CloudFoundry as service [from Pivotal](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/use) or [AppFog](https://www.appfog.com).  Pros and Cons are the same for these services as rolling your own.

**Method 3**

You can [deploy the full CloudFoundry](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/deploying-cf/) instance on top of your favorite IaaS platform (Amazon, WMWare, OpenStack).

Pros:

- All power and control in your hands

Cons:

- Can be difficult to install (I have no success with CF v2.0)
- Can be expensive to run

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you about micro cloud foundry, but you might also want to check out [dokku-alt](https://github.com/dokku-alt/dokku-alt).  It's basically a self-hosted heroku like set up.

Fire up a virtual machine somewhere running Ubuntu 14.04 for the host environment.  Log in and run the Dokku-alt installer script, start pushing apps up by git.  Plus a few commands forthings like adding volumes and databases.  It's remarkably easy.